# Testing Numpy operations

Tags: numpy, numpy-ufunc

Whenever I need to test a moderately complex numpy expression, say,

```
c = np.multiply.outer(a, b)
d = np.einsum('kjij->ijk', c)
```

I end up doings hacks such as, e.g., setting `a` and `b`thus

```
a = np.arange(9).reshape(3,3)
b = a / 10
```

so that I can then track what `d` contains.

This is ugly and not very convenient. Ideally, I would be able to do something like the following:

```
a = np.array(list("abcdefghi")).reshape(3,3)
b = np.array(list("ABCDEFGHI")).reshape(3,3)

c = np.add.outer(a, b)
d = np.einsum('kjij->ijk', c)
```

so that, e.g., `d[0, 1, 2]` could be seen to correspond to 'hB', which is much clearer than .7 (which is what the other assignment to `a` and `b` would give.) This cannot be done, because the ufunc `add` does not take characters.

In summary, once I start chaining a few transformations (an outer product, an einsum, broadcasting or slicing, etc.) I lose track and need to see for myself what my transformations are actually doing. That's when I need to run a few examples, and that's where my current method of doing so strikes me as suboptimal. Is there any standard, or better, way to do this?

Comment: Sorry, you'll explain your problem more.  I don't see what's hackie.  Accepted numpy SO answers do that kind of test/verification all the time.

Comment: @hpaulj, I meant a hack as in, an ugly solution.

Comment: I understand hack implied ugly, but I still don't see what's wrong.  Nor what you are trying to do with strings.

Comment: Thanks. I have edited my question; hopefully what I am after will now be clearer.

Comment: I think the answer to your question might be "reading the manual"

Comment: Thanks, @MartinThoma. What part of the manual would that be? I have read most of it multiple times.

Comment: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html - If I have time after work, I will see if it is unclear and propose to add something. Or maybe you want to do a pull request?

Comment: Thanks again :) It's not really that I don't understand `einsum`. I do. It's rather than once I start chaining a few transformations (an outer product, an einsum, broadcasting or slicing, etc.) I loose track and need to see for myself what my transformation are actually doing. That's when I need to run a few examples, and that's where my current method of doing so strikes me as suboptimal. Perhaps making reference to `einsum` in the question is distracting?

Comment: I have added part of my last comment to the question, in the hope that it will be clarificatory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
In [454]: a = np.array(list("abcdefghi")).reshape(3,3)
     ...: b = np.array(list("ABCDEFGHI")).reshape(3,3)
```

`np.add` can't be used because `add` has not been defined for the string `dtype`:

```
In [455]: c = np.add.outer(a,b)
....
TypeError: ufunc 'add' did not contain a loop with signature matching types dtype('<U1') dtype('<U1') dtype('<U1')
```

But `np.char` has functions that apply Python `string` methods to `ndarray` elements  (these aren't fast, just convenient):

```
Signature: np.char.add(x1, x2)
Docstring:
Return element-wise string concatenation for two arrays of str or unicode.
```

Using broadcasting I can perform your `outer` string concatenation:

```
In [457]: c = np.char.add(a[:,:,None,None], b[None,None,:,:])
In [458]: c.shape
Out[458]: (3, 3, 3, 3)
In [459]: c
Out[459]: 
array([[[['aA', 'aB', 'aC'],
         ['aD', 'aE', 'aF'],
         ['aG', 'aH', 'aI']],

        [['bA', 'bB', 'bC'],
         ['bD', 'bE', 'bF'],
         ['bG', 'bH', 'bI']],

        ....
        [['iA', 'iB', 'iC'],
         ['iD', 'iE', 'iF'],
         ['iG', 'iH', 'iI']]]], dtype='<U2')
```

I was skeptical that `einsum` could handle this array, since normally `einsum` is used for `np.dot` like sum-of-products calculations.  But with this indexing, it is just selecting a diagonal and rearranging axes, so it does work:

```
In [460]: np.einsum('kjij->ijk', c)
Out[460]: 
array([[['aA', 'dA', 'gA'],
        ['bB', 'eB', 'hB'],
        ['cC', 'fC', 'iC']],

       [['aD', 'dD', 'gD'],
        ['bE', 'eE', 'hE'],
        ['cF', 'fF', 'iF']],

       [['aG', 'dG', 'gG'],
        ['bH', 'eH', 'hH'],
        ['cI', 'fI', 'iI']]], dtype='<U2')
```

The `d` from the numeric test case:

```
array([[[0. , 3. , 6. ],
        [1.1, 4.1, 7.1],
        [2.2, 5.2, 8.2]],

       [[0.3, 3.3, 6.3],
        [1.4, 4.4, 7.4],
        [2.5, 5.5, 8.5]],

       [[0.6, 3.6, 6.6],
        [1.7, 4.7, 7.7],
        [2.8, 5.8, 8.8]]])
```

The pattern with these numeric values is just as clear as with strings.

I like to use distinct array shapes where possible, because it makes tracking dimensions across changes easier:

```
In [496]: a3 = np.arange(1,13).reshape(4,3)
     ...: b3 = np.arange(1,7).reshape(2,3) / 10
In [497]: c3 = np.add.outer(a3,b3)
In [498]: d3 = np.einsum('kjij->ijk', c3)
In [499]: c3.shape
Out[499]: (4, 3, 2, 3)
In [500]: d3.shape
Out[500]: (2, 3, 4)
In [501]: d3
Out[501]: 
array([[[ 1.1,  4.1,  7.1, 10.1],
        [ 2.2,  5.2,  8.2, 11.2],
        [ 3.3,  6.3,  9.3, 12.3]],

       [[ 1.4,  4.4,  7.4, 10.4],
        [ 2.5,  5.5,  8.5, 11.5],
        [ 3.6,  6.6,  9.6, 12.6]]])
```

This, for example, would raise an error if I try ''kjik->ijk'.

With numeric values I can perform the `multiply.outer` with `einsum`:

```
In [502]: c4 = np.multiply.outer(a3,b3)
In [503]: np.allclose(c4,np.einsum('ij,kl',a3,b3))
Out[503]: True
In [504]: d4 = np.einsum('kjij->ijk', c4)
In [505]: np.allclose(d4,np.einsum('kj,ij->ijk',a3,b3))
Out[505]: True
In [506]: d4
Out[506]: 
array([[[0.1, 0.4, 0.7, 1. ],
        [0.4, 1. , 1.6, 2.2],
        [0.9, 1.8, 2.7, 3.6]],

       [[0.4, 1.6, 2.8, 4. ],
        [1. , 2.5, 4. , 5.5],
        [1.8, 3.6, 5.4, 7.2]]])
```

That `'kj,ij->ijk'` gives me a better of idea of what is happening than the `d` display.

Another way to put it:

```
(4,3) + (2,3) => (2,3,4)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that is very useful. You are right that this technique won't work when you actually need to multiply arrays. It would be very neat if there was a way to run numpy operations on symbolic arrays as a way of testing behavior.

Comment: There is a symbolic math module, `sympy`.  It can convert its symbolic expressions into `numpy` equivalents, but it can't run `numpy` code.